# How to perform action on dataframes in loop in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have 25 2 column dataframes, and I want to divide column 0 by column 1, to produce column 3 - i.e. adding a 3rd column onto each of the 25 dataframes.

I believe my issue is 'identifying' the dataframes correctly in the loop. So far I have attempted:

```
for country in countries.index:
    data = [country].iloc[:, 0] / [country].iloc[:,1]
    [country].Ratio = [country].data
```

Where countries.index is a list of countries (the index) of a dataframe. But this gives the error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'

I have tried several variations of the above, as well as including vars() before the key, but I seem unable to resolve.

The name of each dataframe matches the name of each country in countries.index

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to loop thorugh values. If you need to loop through the data frames you can create a list of data frames and then you can directly use the apply method of pandas, or you can directly divide the columns of the dataframe.

```
countries = [country1, country2, country3] # list of dataframes 
for country in countries:
   country['ratio'] = country['data1']/country['data2']
```

Now each dataframe in your list will have a new `ratio` column.

Comment: But If I want to perform this for each of the 25 data frames, I would prefer to loop through each one rather than do it one by one

Comment: you can create a list of dataframes and loop though the list. but the correct way is to u apply vector-wise.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting indicates that you're not operating on a dataframe at all. Also, your syntax isn't correct.

```
def add_ratio(df):
    df['ratio'] = df.iloc[:,0] / df.iloc[:,1]
    return df
```

Also, based on your question, it sounds like you mean you have a dataframe that's 25 entries long, not 25 separate dataframes.

if you had a list of your dataframes named "countries":

```
for country in countries:
    country['ratio'] = country.iloc[:,0] / country.iloc[:,1]
```

or

```
 for country in countries:
     country = add_ratio(country)
```

if you are talking about a dataframe named countries with 25 countries in it:

```
countries['ratio'] = countries.iloc[:,0] / countries.iloc[:,1]
```

Comment: Hi mauve, your scenario "if you had a list of dataframes named "countries" " is the situation I am in. This looks good, but it gives the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'" - which appears to be against line #2

Comment: That means you don't have a list of dataframes, you have a list of strings.

Comment: Please share more of the code you're having trouble with. How do you get the DataFrame to start with?

Comment: I have 25 separate dataframes that I am trying to reference by name (country in the above)

Comment: If you have them listed in a list, it sounds like you have quotes around the names. Remove the quotes. I don't know, because I don't see how you created them or where you got them from, etc. I don't know why your code thinks it's a string.